# Error using npm module activedirectory: "TypeError: activedirectory is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I'm trying to use the npm module [activedirectory](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory) in a Meteor app and am getting an error when I try to create a new activedirectory as per the documentation. I'm copying from a working example in another Meteor project so I know the config values are correct, and I can't see any other meaningful differences between my project and the one that works.

I've installed the module activedirectory, it is visible in the node_modules directory.

```
const activedirectory = require('activedirectory');

function getUserDataFromAD(username) {
    console.log(`typeof activedirectory ${typeof activedirectory}`);

    var AD = new activedirectory({
        url:'ldap://validurl',
        baseDN:'validDN',
        username:validUN,
        password:validPW,
    });
}
```

In the console I see:

```
typeof activedirectory object
I20180720-12:33:09.073(1)? Exception while invoking method 'login' TypeError: activedirectory is not a constructor
```

Any ideas? This has me baffled!

Comment: Can you try importing it like that: `var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');` ?

Comment: Thanks, I did try that. See below - it seems the latest Meteor is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had not installed the activedirectory package to this project. A silly oversight but I would have expected the errors to be more helpful.